# Azure Cosmos DB client throws "HttpRequestException: attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" underneath

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I use **CosmosClient** from ***SDK Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.28.0*** in ASP.NET Core 3.1 in Azure Durable Function. This client is getting and sending data from/to my cosmos instance (Core (SQL)) and it works fine but I see that it constantly throws exception in following http request for metadata

**GET 169.254.169.254/metadata/instance**

*System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.*

I use following configuration:

```
  private static void RegisterCosmosDbClient(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(c => new SocketsHttpHandler()
            {
                PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), // Customize this value based on desired DNS refresh timer
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = 20, // Customize the maximum number of allowed connections
            }).As<SocketsHttpHandler>().SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(
                    x =>
                    {
                        var cosmosDbOptions = x.Resolve<CosmosDbOptions>();
                        var socketsHttpHandler = x.Resolve<SocketsHttpHandler>();
                        return new CosmosClient(cosmosDbOptions.ConnectionString, new CosmosClientOptions()
                        {
                            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                            PortReuseMode = PortReuseMode.PrivatePortPool,
                            IdleTcpConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59),
                            SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
                            {
                                PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                            },
                            HttpClientFactory = () => new HttpClient(socketsHttpHandler, disposeHandler: false)
                        });
                    })
                .AsSelf()
                .SingleInstance();
   }
```

I also tried approach with passing IHttpClientFactory [from this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/httpclientfactory-cosmos-db-net-sdk/) but it didn't help.

Comment: I updated project to .net6, azure function to v4 and Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos to 3.29.0 but error still occurs.

Comment: You will get above error when the socket is probably being held by a process. Find out which one by using `netstat -o`.

Try to **restart** the **Host Network Service** on windows service program
`
net stop hns
net start hns
`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are no new sockets available in your environment therefore you are getting the socket forbidden error. Please review how to [manage connection for Azure Cosmos DB clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#azure-cosmos-db-clients) and you should [use a singleton Azure Cosmos DB client for the lifetime of your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql?tabs=trace-net-core#sdk-usage) to resolve the issue. In case if you still facing the issue leveraging the singleton object then please let me know so we can further review it.

Comment: I registered it as a single instance as you can see from my example. Right now I am applying suggestions from Mattias related with infrastructure. Azure functions running on Windows, built as X64, all DLLs co-located.

Comment: Nothing helped. I tried most basic approach from documentation you sent without DI and problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

That particular IP and path is for https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows

The SDK is attempting to detect the Azure information. It could mean for Durable Functions, this information and endpoint is not available.

This does not affect SDK operations and should not block you from performing other actions on the CosmosClient instance.

Comment: but isn't it affecting performance of my app? Moreover I have the same situation with Azure Function (not Durable one).

Comment: It is affecting performance because queries are doing extra network requests that could be eliminated if the conditions in the article are met (running on Windows, built as X64, all DLLs co-located). It won't make your queries not execute though.

Comment: Nothing helped. I created empty azure function register everything as singleton and still see problems with gathering metadata. Moreover I also tried most basic approach from documentation without DI and problem still occurs. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#azure-cosmos-db-clients

I can't afford any performance slow downs.

Comment: These requests have nothing to do with performance, they are not done inline with your operations though. The SDK does 1 of these requests when it starts, so you should see 1 error, if you are continuously seeing them, means you are potentially creating many clients.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this, and found this annoying, when calling CosmosDb outside of Azure.

If you really want to disable this call, you can, with the usual caveats about using reflection on an external library.

```
    var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CosmosClient));
    var type = assembly?.GetType("Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Telemetry.VmMetadataApiHandler");
    var field = type?.GetField("isInitialized", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    field?.SetValue(type, true);
```

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/ebd1b91a26547721ef232ef597d878144889b80b/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Telemetry/VmMetadataApiHandler.cs#L29

Comment: Vote if you want this fixed: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/4187